# Windows.Storage error: the type of namespace Storage does not exist in namespace windows

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am very new to C#, visual studio, and related Microsoft work. So it is very likely that I messed something up and I hope some one can help me a bit on this.

I create an Console application and I am trying to run some tutorial C# code. There is a red line under when I try to load Windos.Storage.Pickers and all namespaces after it. I attempt to add the references, but I can't find what I need there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


using Windows;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Media.FaceAnalysis;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FaceDetector faceDetector;
            IList<DetectedFace> detectedFaces;

            FileOpenPicker photoPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            photoPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            photoPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            photoPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            photoPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            photoPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            photoPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");

            StorageFile photoFile = await photoPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (photoFile == null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the namespace you are tying to use is use for UWP development.
The problem is that you are trying to use it in Console Development.

[Read about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers)

Comment: So I am installing the win10 sdk right now. After the installation I still don't have the windows universal project type when I attempted to create projects.

Comment: Can also be used for WPF projects.